# Is it possible to set Intel Graphics maximum power state via Windows power options

Tags: windows, graphics-card, cpu, power-supply, intel-graphics

My cpu was overheating so I decided to decrease it's frequency.
I have done that with "Power options" -> "Change plan settings" -> "Change advanced power settings" -> "Processor power management" -> "Maximum processor state".

The problem is that the maximum state is not working for the cpu graphics module (NOTE that this is not a separate GPU device, it is the graphics module in the Intel Processor, [see](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/embedded/software/hd-gma/hd-graphics-drivers-and-graphics-media-accelerator-drivers-documentation.html)).
I tested it with [aida.](https://www.aida64.com/)
When I stress cpu(without the graphics module) the temperature is never higher than 50 grads. However if I start streesing the graphics module the temperature is increasing up to maximum and the cpu starts throttling.

How can I bound the max state of the whole cpu (including the graphics module) via Windows Power Options?

**EDIT.** The "GPU 1" in the test is the cpu graphic module. The "GPU 2" is the NVIDIA videocard. The test shows that both GPU's are stressed, however only GPU 1 is loaded and GPU 2 is not. Therefore the temperature increase is going only from Intel Graphics as the temperature of NVIDIA is not changing while stressing.

**The start of the test**
[image]

**Stressing only cpu**
[image]

**Stressing cpu with Intel HD Graphics**
[image]

Comment: Your GPU seems to have a problem. Perhaps your computer needs cleaner airways, or perhaps the GPU needs new thermal paste. What are your computer and GPU models? Did you overclock anything?

Comment: @harrymc this is not a separate GPU it is the graphics module inside the Intel processor, [see more details here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/embedded/software/hd-gma/hd-graphics-drivers-and-graphics-media-accelerator-drivers-documentation.html)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood, maybe because your screenshots show the CPU temperature, not the GPU. You might find a product that can display the GPU temp (if it has sensors). If the CPU temp rises because the GPU is stressed, this means that the computer case is overheating. You may clean well the airways for starters. Which model is the computer? Desktop or laptop?

Comment: @harrymc I edited the question. The GPU (NVIDIA) temperature is not changing in this test (as task manager shows). Even if the test launches the test for the both GPUs (NVIDIA and Intel HD Graphics (which is "inside" the cpu)) the NVIDIA GPU is not loaded, so the heat increase goes from the CPU. And the problem is that while the CPU maximum power is bounded by Windows Power Options, the Intel HD Graphics is not

Comment: You're mixing terms and making it hard to understand. The CPU is distinct from the Intel HD Graphics, their only common point is the motherboard to which they are soldered. Could you please clarify your question in view of this comment?

Comment: @harrymc please read this [What Is the Difference Between Integrated Graphics and Discrete Graphics](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000057824/graphics.html)

Comment: I think you have some serious misunderstandings of the subject, but I'm out of here.